# How to import GDAL lib Qt, Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, import, gdal

i have some problem with gdal lib. I am using mingw32 in qt and i download from [here](http://gisinternals.com/release.php) gdal lib. Then, when i try import gdal from qt. i this error for GDALAllRegister(); function in main.cpp side.

My import way is: right-click on project -> add library -> external library -> choose path of gdal_i.lib -> choose dynamic link instead of static -> okey , i had this error : error: undefined reference to `GDALAllRegister@0'.

My .pro file:

```
unix:!macx|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Downloads/release-1911-x64-gdal-3-1-2-mapserver-7-6-1-libs/lib/ -lgdal_i

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../Downloads/release-1911-x64-gdal-3-1-2-mapserver-7-6-1-libs/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../Downloads/release-1911-x64-gdal-3-1-2-mapserver-7-6-1-libs/include
```

My main.cpp file includes:

```
#include "gdal.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
```

qt see my header file and when i ctrl+click on GDALAllRegister() function, opening gdal.h header. But i had error that i just indicated.

What is my lib problem? How can i import GDAL in QT?